# When are host keys for the server generated

Tags: rhel, system-installation, kickstart

I am writing a hardening script to be run by kickstart during the post-installation phase.  One of the requirements is to change the permissions on /etc/ssh/ssh_host*key files.  My problem is that those keys are not generated when the script is run.  I have two questions:

1. When are those keys generated during the installation process?
2. Will I break anything if I generate them with my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the keys are generated during first start of the server (after install).

About generate new one: yes, there is no problem as far as they are described (with filenames) in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. And you restart `sshd` after generation. But if you have already some host/user which get the server public key (before new generation) this may lead to errors in ssh sessions.

Comment: @ninov Thanks.  The ssh server was not started during the installation.  My solution was to generate the keys mysql with ```ssh-keygen -A``` rather then starting the ssh server during the installation process.  It didn't break anything.